# Meaning of “adjoined”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Good evening. Anyone can explain me what the meaning of “adjoined”? 
The quote where i saw this word was “we don’t have any more single rooms available, with the exception of one adjoined room”

Comment: Are you asking about *adjoined* or *adjourned*?

Comment: The question that I saw, its says “adjoined”.

Comment: [explain the meaning of x to me]

Comment: adjoining rooms in hotel lingo means one room next to another.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I’m going to use this post to ask another thing. Can you explain me what the differente between “doorman” and “porter”?

Comment: @Andreia that’s a different question, please open a new Q-and-A. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: @Lambie please add as an answer – this is the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general meaning of *adjoined* is:

> close to or in contact with one another
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjoined)*</sub>
>
> a room, building, or piece of land that adjoins something is next to it and connected to it
>   <sub>*from [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/adjoin)*</sub>

In the specific context of hotel rooms, it refers to rooms that are physically next to each other, sharing a wall; and there is a door in that wall, so that a larger group of people could rent the pair of rooms and treat them as a single unit.

Renting only one of an adjoined pair of rooms is therefore often seen as less desirable because of the opportunity for your neighbor to sound louder, as the door is not nearly as sound-resistant as a wall; and you also have to make sure that you keep the door properly secured (not usually an issue, as it is lockable from both sides, but still something you want to be certain of).

Comment: In the context of any rooms, adjoin means next to, in fact. It could be a house, office or hotel. And hotel rooms are not "rented".

Comment: @Lambie I genuinely cannot think of a better word than "rented"... do you have an alternative in mind?

Comment: I would just say getting a room. :)